# How many monoids, groups, etc are there defined on a finite set of size $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a set $X$. We can define a binary relation $\cdot :X\times X\to X$, and get an algebraic structure $(X,\cdot)$.

There are $|X|^{|X|^2}$ such binary relations that can be defined. I.e. let $N=n^{n^2}$ where $n=|X|$.

Now, if we introduce axioms on $\cdot$, the amount of binary relations we can define will of course shrink. **Denote by $N_A$ the amount of possible binary relations that satisfy axioms $A$**. **Denote by $N_A^*$ the number of them that are unique up to isomorphism.** $N_A$ and $N_A^*$ are obviously a functions of $n$.

I am wondering how much the different algebraic axioms constrain the size $N_A,N_A^*$, such as associativity, commutativity, existence of inverses, etc. How does $N_A,N_A^*$ depend on the different axioms?

- Are there precise formulas for $N_A$ and $N_A^*$, depending on the common axioms as a function of $n$? (Associativity, inverses, identity, commutativity,...)
- Are there interesting interaction effects between the axioms?
- Is there a name for the topic I’m pointing to in this question?

Comment: For groups see the first entry [A000001](https://oeis.org/A000001) in OEIS and its links.

Comment: Are you also interested in the number of such structures up to isomorphism?

Comment: There are some related questions about the case of [groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595203/how-many-groups-there-are-on-a-finite-set) and [semigroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105438/how-many-associative-binary-operations-there-are-on-a-finite-set).

Comment: @Max, I’ve edited the question.

Comment: You have a very nice research project proposal.

Comment: Do we have any updates on this? I am of the opinion this is a very important research problem, that we will inevitably have to start thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

For groups this is a well studied problem with no easy answer. See [finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) classification for reference. If you take enough axioms though then this computation can become quite simple, for instance number of finite abelian groups of order $n$ can be easily described look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786525/abelian-groups-of-order-n) for example.

In summary it can go both ways.